# Capture kernel panic console messages?

Tags: boot, kernel

Ubuntu version 22.10
Dual boot. Select Ubuntu in grub.
Booting from SSD containing only Ubuntu

Is there a way to capture console messages emitted during boot, specifically when there is a kernel panic?

Answer (score 0):

`dmesg` displays start up messages (has to be run as root or with `sudo`)

Comment: @ jtalics I had to preface that with sudo. Ubuntu Mate 20.04